# Which pronoun to use when responding to "Is this your father?"

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, british-english

What is the right answer for this question?

[image]

The picture shows a woman holding a young child. 
The question is "Is this your father?" The answer is "no", but how does one say this as a complete sentence? Should I say "No, **he** isn't." or "No, **she** isn't".

Comment: The answer to the question is "no". Even if the adult who looks like a woman is in fact a man, the answer is still "no".

Comment: More context needs to be added. Why is this question a problem for you?

Comment: No,she isn't   ---No,he isn't------No,it isn't

Comment: Use "she." You would not use "he" because the pronoun should agree with (match) the thing that is there, rather than the concept that it doesn't equal.

Comment: "Is this your father" has an American flavour, like when they answer the telephone with "who is this?" In British English we ask "who are you?" and transferring that to the naff question promoted, would be "Is she your father?".

Comment: I would say, "No, that's not my father." That eliminates your gender quandary.

Comment: What's wrong with "No, **it** isn't"?  "It" doesn't necessarily refer to inanimate objects; we sometimes use it for situations too, like "It was my father at the door."

Comment: The difficulty is that you don't just have to know which sentences are correct (there are many, many possibilities - these could include "No, neither of the people in the picture is my father" or "I'm sorry, that's none of your business") - if you're a learner, you also have to try to read the mind of the person marking your work, who might have a particular sentence in mind.  I think @J.R.'s "No, that's not my father" works well.

Comment: @WeatherVane doesn't that sound curt?

Comment: @user178049 yes it is, but the question was originally "What is the right answer for this question?"

Answer (score 2):

The simplest answer is to negate the question : "Is this X?" "No, this is not X." In this case : "Is this your father?" "No, this is not my father."

Alternatively you can be more informative by stating who the person is : "No, this is my mother."

Of the suggestions you provide, "No, she is not" is correct. The word "this" in the question "Is this your father?" refers to the adult in the picture, who is a female. So the answer cannot be "No, he is not my father" because "this" is a feminine object which is referred to as "she".